# Find the maximum in each row

Tags: excel, vba, max, multiple-columns

I have three columns of data:
[image]

I'd like to find the maximum value of each row and place it in column E on the corresponding row.
For example, for first row: 41.13, second row: 2143.404 and so on.

```vb
Dim LastRowIdent As Long, LastRowCant As Long

With Sheets("LOL")

    LastRowIdent = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A2:A" & LastRowIdent).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Animal").Range("A5") 
    LastRowCant = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("G2:G" & LastRowCant).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Animal").Range("B5") 
        
End With
    
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
With Sheets("Animal")
        
    Dim NumSheet As Long
    NumSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 6
        
    Range("F:F").Copy
    Range("G:G").Resize(, NumSheet).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, Copyorigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            
    Range("E:E").Copy
    vRange("F:F").Resize(, NumSheet).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, Copyorigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        
    Range("C:C").Copy
    Range("D:D").Resize(, NumSheet).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, Copyorigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        
    Dim M As Long
    For M = 1 To NumSheet + 1
        Dim LastRowPrec As Long
        LastRowPrec = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2 + M).Cells(.Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row - 2
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2 + M).Range("K2:K" & LastRowPrec).Copy Destination:=.Cells(5, 2 + M)
    Next M
    
End With
```

Comment: `=MAX(A1:C1)`????

Comment: Yes but how do I do it using vba for each row?

Comment: `Range("E1:E24").Formula = "=MAX(A1:C1)"`... what did you try?

Comment: My problem is that my range is ```Range(.Cells(5, 4 + NumSheet + 1), .Cells(LastRowMax, 4 + NumSheet + 1)``` because I won't know the last row (in the image is 24 but in my case is not fixed) and the other values depend on some other sheets

Comment: So how can I do for example ```"=MAX(range not fixed)"```?

Comment: I think you need to [edit] your question to reflect your actual problem and include the code you've tried so far.

Comment: I did, I posted my code.

Comment: Where's the relevant portion to generate the `Max`?

Comment: The part where I copy the columns in D, there will be x columns copied after D and I need to get the maximum of the rows of these columns. For example: if ```NumSheet``` is 2, I will have 3 columns of data from which I'll want to get the maximum, but if ```NumSheet``` is 3, I'll have 4 columns of data. That is the reason my max(range) is not fixed, it depends on this value that changes in function of the sheets I have in my workbook.

Comment: Then get the `Address` from the `Range` in question and use that in a `MAX` formula.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is I do not know how to get this address, that is where I'm stuck

Comment: `.Rows(1).Address(False, False)` on the range in question?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, do you mean using that as: ```=MAX(.Rows(1).Address(False, False)) = Range(.Cells(5, 4 + NumSheet), .Cells(LastRowMax, 4 + NumSheet)```? the last part is the range of the column where I want to copy the maximum value.

Comment: In my example as I have only 3 columns of data, this works: ```Range(.Cells(5, 4 + NumSheet), .Cells(LastRowMax, 4 + NumSheet)).Formula = "=MAX(C5:E5)"```, my problem is that the range ```C5:E5``` is not fixed and can change to ```C5:D5```, ```C5:F5```, ```C5:G5```, etc

Comment: Finally! I got it, yes, it was using Address(False, False), thank you so much!! I'll update my post and mark your answer as correct! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @BigBen, the line I was looking for was:
`Range(.Cells(5, 4 + NumSheet), .Cells(LastRowMax, 4 + NumSheet)).Formula = "=MAX(" & .Cells(5, 3).Address(False, False) & ":" & .Cells(5, 3 + NumSheet).Address(False, False) & ")"`